# Rendering elements of an array from a document in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm extremely new to Meteor and haven't been able to find the answer to something that's probably laughably simple.

I have a Meteor collection called Ingredients:

```
Ingredients = new Mongo.Collections("ingredients");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
   Template.body.helpers({
      ingredients: function() {
         return Ingredients.find({});
   });
}
```

Which is populated with documents like the following:

```
{ name: Boneless Pork Chop,
  tags: [Paleo, Pork, Local] }
```

Right now I'm rendering the name in a template, as follows:

```
<template name="ingredient">
   <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
   </tr>
</template>
```

What I need to figure out now is how to also render the individual elements of the 'tags' array in that template. Preferably, I'd like to render them in such a way that later I could assign a click event to each of them so they could be individually removed or edited... which from my earlier reading means I might want to put the tags in their own collection and join them to the Ingredients documents by an ID, which is perfectly find with me if that's a better pattern.

Little help? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far? There are indeed a number of resources describing how you could do that. Could you point us to the ones you've tried and tell us what didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use #each to print an array in meteor.

```
<template name="ingredient">
    <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>
          {{#each tags}}
            {{this}}
          {{/each}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```